# Show JMenu in JPanel without frame.setJMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jmenubar, astah

I would like to add a JMenuBar to a Jpanel. I tried:

```
 p.add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Also: I don't want to do use JSetMenu method on the JFrame because I'm currently making a Astah-plugin and I would like the Jpanel (where the Jmenubar is in) to be in Astah.

How do I set a JMenuBar to a Jpanel so it goes on the top?
I would like to put all the content in the Jpanel and put this in Astah.

The code to put it in Astah:

```
import com.change_vision.jude.api.inf.project.ProjectAccessor;
import com.change_vision.jude.api.inf.project.ProjectAccessorFactory;
import com.change_vision.jude.api.inf.project.ProjectEvent;
import com.change_vision.jude.api.inf.project.ProjectEventListener;
import com.change_vision.jude.api.inf.ui.IPluginExtraTabView;
import com.change_vision.jude.api.inf.ui.ISelectionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class showobjects extends JPanel implements IPluginExtraTabView, ProjectEventListener {
public showobjects () {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(createLabelPane());
    addProjectEventListener();
}

private void addProjectEventListener() {
    try {
        ProjectAccessor projectAccessor = ProjectAccessorFactory.getProjectAccessor();
        projectAccessor.addProjectEventListener(this);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}

private Container createLabelPane() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("showobjects ");
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(label);

    showobjects  app = new showobjects ();
    JPanel mainJpanel  = app.createJPanel();


    return mainJpanel;
}

@Override
public void projectChanged(ProjectEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void projectClosed(ProjectEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void projectOpened(ProjectEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void addSelectionListener(ISelectionListener listener) {
}

@Override
public Component getComponent() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public String getDescription() {
    return "Show showobjects  here";
}

@Override
public String getTitle() {
    return "showobjects ";
}

public void activated() {

}

public void deactivated() {

}
}
```

Comment: I did a very simply test using a `JPanel` and `BorderLayout` and it works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I did a very simple test and it works fine me. Based on what I can deduce from your code, you're using...

```
mainJPanel.add(AuguSoftModellerobjectsNew.createMenuBar());
```

which would place the `JMenuBar` in the `CENTRE` (or default) position of the panel, which will be hidden by other components you also add there

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                mb.add(new JMenu("Test"));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(mb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

}
```

Comment: how do I put the menu bar on the op and put the other stuff in the center? Is a borderlayout good for doing this? Your help would be very appreciated. I don't know how to put a menubar manually to the JPanel and also being able to show other components. Because at the moment everything is showing in the center. @MadProgrammer

Comment: To put components in the "centre" position, you probably need a component which acts as the primary content pane for those components, similarly to what I've shown above. If you add components to the `TestPane`, they will be contained within it, but the `TestPane` itself will occupy the centre position

Comment: I tried but it dosen't work, i made a main JPanel and two other panels (one for the jmenubar) and another for other content. I added the two jpanels to the main Jpanel en set the jmenubar, borderlayout to north. What did i do wrong? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Based on everything I've seen, I would highly recommend you take a look at [How to use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)